# Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/wt/myfolder/Todo/ios/QRCodeFrameProcessor/QRCodeFrameProcessor.swift'

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

> At first my Project running fine. when I add this command according to
> the library of **react-native-vision-camera** it adds some files in IOS
> folder. I run this command **npx vision-camera-plugin-builder iOS**
> and it add some folder of frame processor. after that it gives some
> error whenever I run the code.  after that I delete all the folders of
> QRFrameProcessing which was created . now I received another error

```
SwiftCompile normal x86_64 Compiling\ QRCodeFrameProcessor.swift /Users/wt/myprojects/todo/ios/QRCodeFrameProcessor/QRCodeFrameProcessor.swift (in target 'todo' from project 'todo')

/Users/wt/myprojects/todo/ios/ios/QRCodeFrameProcessor/QRCodeFrameProcessor.swift:1:2: error: @objc attribute used without importing module 'Foundation'
@objc(QRCodeFrameProcessorPlugin)
```

I just need to know that how to delete all the frame Processors which I have added from the above command I mentioned

[this is the link where I add frame processor for IOS](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/frame-processors-plugins-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the Frame Processor manual setup instructions and revert these changes. For example for SWIFT version is like this:

- Remove QRCodeFrameProcessorPlugin.swift
- Remove generated BrigingHeaders files
- Remove QRCodeFrameProcessorPlugin.m

https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/frame-processors-plugins-ios/#manual-setup

Comment: is there any command available where I delete QRframeProcessor

Comment: unfortunately nope just delete it by hand.

Comment: I have deleted all the files but still getting this error

Comment: @ABDULLAH the same error?

Comment: yes the same error

Comment: in the documentation they didn't show the how to delete the generated files

Comment: can you check this file exists? QRCodeFrameProcessor/QRCodeFrameProcessor.swift

Comment: I haven't said that documentation had it, I said you can delete files they created manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250221/discussion-between-abdullah-and-kirill-novikov).